# Is the syncing time a good benchmark to evaluate Monero resource requirement with high tx/s?

Tags: monerod, transaction-volume

It took about 6h to sync my node with monerod 0.10.0
(It might have taken less time, I can't recall the exact time unfortunately)

Monero has about 240,000 tx in the blockchain last year. (moneroblocks.info)

I couldn't find the Monero total tx number.

I will assume 300,000 should be a good estimate.

That seems to suggest my computer can handle 300,000 x 4 = 1,200,000 tx a day.
About 14 tx/s

It is a fair estimate?

Comment: sync time and the maximum number of transactions that can be validated per second are not the same. Most modern computers can handle far more tx/s. Bandwidth appears to be a common limiting factor: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/405/how-many-transactions-per-second-can-the-monero-network-handle

Answer (score 1):

It's going to vary quite a bit between machines, the CONOP (Cost Of Node OPeration) should hopefully average out such that the tps of any given day will be reflective of the number of nodes in operation to verify and relay those transactions without performance degrading to the point that miners lose money.

This [video](https://m.reddit.com/r/btc/comments/4ponee/video_of_riccardo_fluffypony_spagni_speaking_at/) on dynamic blocksizes and CONOP breakdown to determine decentralisation and scaling may provide some useful info on the subject.